# Trying to fit carouFredSel in a variable-width container

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, caroufredsel

I am trying to create a site using the Responsive Grid System. The width of the columns depends on the width of the browser window. Within these columns, I'm putting a carouFredSel slideshow. The intent is to have an image that fills the width of the column, and use carouFredSel to crossfade between images.

The problem is that my images aren't showing up at the right size; the left and right edges are getting clipped off. When I use Chrome to inspect, it reports that my main column (.span_5_of_10) is 613px wide, as it should be, and that carouFredSel's wrapper div is the same size, but the posterCarousel div is 661px wide. I can't figure out why.

I can set the width of the images in the CSS to 661px and that fixes everything, but then my design won't be responsive. How can I get carouFredSel to fit in a variable-width container?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col span_5_of_10">
    <div class="posterCarousel">
        <img src="img/The-World-Needs-Heroes---Superman.png">
        <img src="img/The-World-Needs-Heroes---Knight.png">
        <img src="img/The-World-Needs-Heroes---Swashbuckler.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript at the bottom of the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        /*  CarouFredSel: a circular, responsive jQuery carousel.
            Configuration created by the "Configuration Robot"
            at caroufredsel.dev7studios.com
        */
        $(".posterCarousel").carouFredSel({
            width: "100%",
            items: {
                width: "100%"
            },
            scroll: {
                fx: "crossfade",
                pauseonhover: true
            },
            auto: 3000
        });

    });

</script>
```

And the CSS controlling my images:

```
.posterCarousel img {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally wanted to solve this with CSS or by reconfiguring carouFredSel, but after walking away for the problem for an evening I decided it made sense to write more JavaScript to fix a JavaScript problem.

I wrote a function to get the current width of the column and then set the image CSS to the appropriate value:

```
function setMainColumnWidth(){
    var mainColumnWidth = $(".span_5_of_10:first").width();
    $(".posterCarousel img").css("width", mainColumnWidth);
}
```

Then I call this function when the page loads and every time the window gets resized:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setMainColumnWidth();
    /* carouFredSel code goes here */
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    setMainColumnWidth();
});
```

Problem solved!